# Opening a datepicker when clicked on the image

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need a simple datepicker when clicked on an image:
Here is jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=r8tGtELorR)
I replaced this line:

```
<p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

with this line:

```
<p>Date: <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/calendar.png" id="datepicker"></p>
```

But datepicker didn't open up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it:
Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
<script>
$("#dp").datepicker({ buttonImage: 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQRgf5_uPY45M_ztXaWpb_XVkpaNIG_XvB6EKlGtYQIDin0wjlPw', buttonImageOnly: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showOn: 'both', });
</script>
```